# How to took up artifact version built with Gradle from sources

Tags: java, gradle

When using Maven, it's easy to look up latest version of `SNAPSHOT` artifact by going to parent's `pom.xml`:

https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L33

But where do I look to get the same in Gradle?
For example I couldn't find any version in the sources here:

https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java

And if it's impossible, then why? How Gradle knows which version to build? Is this information external to the source code?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the project setup. The project you link to, according to their [`RELEASING.md`](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/RELEASING.md), use the tag name for the version.

> 3. Create a new release on GitHub. The tag name is used as the version, so please keep the tag name plain (e.g. 1.2.3).

This is done by the Travis build script, [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/.travis.yml), specifically the line

```
script: ./gradlew -Pversion=$TRAVIS_TAG release
```

Some projects will explicitly put a `version=x.y.z` in their gradle file, others will provide it explicitly on build (similar to the Travis script used).

The advantage of this setup is that the version is never in the script, and you can't get merge conflicts or accidental version overwrites on this.

Comment: Another option is to put your version in a separate file as I do [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/version.txt) and reference it in Gradle [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/build.gradle#L12). This way you can see a history in git, you can also update version.txt via command line before a release build eg `echo x.y.z > version.txt && gradle release`